# PPT Macro go to last instance of certain slide layout

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, macros

I have a macro (below) for a button that I need to use.  What I want to do is change the value of `lngCurr` to the layout 'section header' and make it so when the macro runs, it takes the user back to the last instance of a slide of that particular layout.

`Dim lngCurr As Long
lngCurr = SlideShowWindows(1).View.CurrentShowPosition
SlideShowWindows(1).View.GotoSlide (lngCurr - 1), msoTrue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function that returns the slide index of the last slide with the specified layout.
That plus what you've got should get you there.

```
Sub Test()
    MsgBox LastSlideWithLayout("Section header")
End Sub

Function LastSlideWithLayout(sLayoutName As String) As Long

    Dim oSl As Slide
    Dim x As Long

    For x = ActivePresentation.Slides.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set oSl = ActivePresentation.Slides(x)
        If UCase(oSl.CustomLayout.Name) = UCase(sLayoutName) Then
            LastSlideWithLayout = x
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

    ' return 0 to indicate that no slides with this layout were found
    LastSlideWithLayout = 0

End Function
```